# Tag select in html is tall in chrome,safari mac

Tags: html, macos, google-chrome, safari

when select tag have many option, it look normal in chrome, firefox, safari of linux and window, but on mac , it look weird, it have height equal screen height. You can see it in image:
[image]

How i fix it ? Thank you very much. This only occur chrome and safari on mac .
Code is very simple, it only default select tag in html.

```
<select class="form-control ap_select2" type="number" name="year">
    <?php
        $minYear = config('init.min_date_construction_year');
        $maxYear = config('init.max_date_construction_year');
        for ($i=$minYear; $i<=$maxYear; $i++) {
    ?>
   <option value="{{$i}}" <?php if(old('year')==$i) echo 'selected'; ?> >{{$i}}</option>
   <?php
      }
   ?>
</select>
```

Comment: How can this be reproduced without codes? I think it will be better if you upload some code snippet

Comment: Because code is very simple, it only tag select default in html , not custom or css